# Error: 550 Can't create directory: No such file or directory

Tags: gruntjs

I get this error when using `grunt-ftp-deploy`:

```
Error creating new remote folder /html/ux-protos-test/ --> Error: 550 Can't create directory: No such file or directory
```

This is my grunt task file:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    auth: {
      host: 'ux.machinas.com',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'key1'
    },
    src: 'build/templates',
    dest: 'html/ux-protos-test',
    exclusions: [
      '.DS_Store',
      '.gitignore',
      '.ftppass'
    ]
  }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is it possible the `html` directory does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a **full path** in dest, not a relative one.

Probably include the home directory of the user you're deploying under, like: `/home/your_user/public_html/html/ux-protos-test`